# How to get the value from sum() in a Grails criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.3

I can't use the `+` operator with `resultado[0] + obj.nopersonas`, `nopersonas` is an Integer.

```
fhinicio(blank:false, validator : { val, obj ->
    def diff = groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus(obj.fhfinal, val)
    def total = diff.hours*60 + diff.minutes
    if (total < 15){
        return "reserva.fhfinal.tiempo.min.label"
    } else {            
        if (total > 60) {
            return "reserva.fhfinal.tiempo.max.label"
        } else {
            def reserva = Reserva.createCriteria()
            def resultado = reserva.list() {
                or {
                    and {
                        ge('fhinicio', val)
                        le('fhinicio', obj.fhfinal)
                    }
                    and {
                        ge('fhfinal', val)
                        le('fhfinal', obj.fhfinal)
                    }
                }

                projections {
                    sum('nopersonas')
                }
            } 

            //this is not working   
            def aff = resultado[0] + obj.nopersonas
```

> Cannot execute null+null. Stacktrace follows: Message: Cannot execute null+null

Comment: Well it seems `resultado[0]` and `obj.nopersonas` both are `null`. Check by debugging or simply printing the values if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems to resolve:

1. The criteria query is returning null
2. `obj.nopersonas` is null

## The criteria query

To fix the criteria query, start without the projection:

```
def reserva = Reserva.createCriteria()
def resultado = reserva.list {
    or {
        and {
            ge('fhinicio', val)
            le('fhinicio', obj.fhfinal)
        }
        and {
            ge('fhfinal', val)
            le('fhfinal', obj.fhfinal)
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you're getting the appropriate instances of `Reserva`. Then, add the projection and since you're expecting a single value, use the get() method instead of list().

```
def reserva = Reserva.createCriteria()
def resultado = reserva.get {
    or {
        and {
            ge('fhinicio', val)
            le('fhinicio', obj.fhfinal)
        }
        and {
            ge('fhfinal', val)
            le('fhfinal', obj.fhfinal)
        }
    }

    projections {
        sum('nopersonas')
    }
} 

def aff = resultado + obj.nopersonas
```

## obj.nopersonas

Since `obj.nopersonas` is null, I'm assuming the property is nullable. If the property is supposed to be nullable, then you'll need to account for that in your validator.

Answer (score 0):

It is working.

Integer variable_name = Integer.valueOf(resultado[0].toString())

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle the null condition:

```
def aff = (resultado[0] ?: 0) + (obj.nopersonas ?: 0)
```